# NodeJS exec() command for both Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, windows, ubuntu, npm, gulp

Using NodeJS, NPM, and Gulp.

I want to build a gulp task to run JSDoc that works on Ubuntu and Windows.

This works on Ubuntu...

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

return function(cb) {
  exec('node node_modules/.bin/jsdoc -c jsdoc-conf.json', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    cb(err);
  });
};
```

And this works on Windows...

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

return function(cb) {
  exec('node_modules\\.bin\\jsdoc -c jsdoc-conf.json', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    cb(err);
  });
};
```

Needless to say, neither works on the other.  How do others solve this type of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node has `process.platform`, which... "returns a string identifying the operating system platform on which the Node.js process is running. For instance `darwin`, `freebsd`, `linux`, `sunos` or `win32`"

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_platform

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

return function(cb) {
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    // Windows OS
  } else {
    // everything else
  }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using [path.resolve](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_path), which should provide you with a full path to the file regardless of the platform.

Answer (score 1):

Using [path.resolve](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths):

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const path = require('path');

return function(cb) {
  let command = `node ${path.resolve('node_modules/.bin/jsdoc')} -c jsdoc-conf.json`;

  exec(command, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    cb(err);
  });
};
```

Comment: I would recommend using path.resolve or path.posix.resolve or path.win32.resolve if you want a specific platform type of path

Comment: @justin.m.chase re-implemented using path.resolve, much cleaner. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

path.join('a', 'b', 'c') is recommended to avoid setting / or \ yourself, and you will get the right path a\b\c or a/b/c in your current platform.